# how to run a jQuery function after certain element is displayed

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog

I have a modal that is displayed only once (like a dialog box) after user logged-in firstly. And also I've got a function in that modal file that is supposed to run if modal is displayed.
Here is function:

```
$('#some_element').(function someFunc() {
      console.log("gUM is used now");
      //some stuff to do
});
```

I tried on('click') and it works fine. But I don't need it.
Also, I tried on('load'), but it works before modal is displayed. 
Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can try on load but you need to check if display is block then the modal is visible :)

Comment: @guradio thanks for your replay! You mean something like that:
function() {
      if modal displayed (){
          $('#some_element').(function someFunc() {
                   console.log("gUM is used now");
                    //some stuff to do
});
)
but how can check if modal displayed?

Comment: check the visibility of modal if block it is visible it none it is hidden

Answer (score 0):

Hello i think you can use events. for example for jquery dialog there is many events and function to know if dialod is open http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#method-isOpen and some events like [open](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#event-open) or [beforeClose](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#event-beforeClose) or you can use jquery to detect if the element is visible `$("#SomeElement").is(":visible")`

Answer (score 0):

Not an ideal solution but you could start a timer in on load, and have it run a function every half second to check if the modal is visible:

```
var checkModalTimer;

$(document).ready(function() {
  checkModalTimer = setInterval(function() {
     if ($('modal').is(':visible')) {
       // do your function
       clearInterval(checkModalTimer);
     }
  }, 500);
});
```